# interpret unknown piece of powershell related to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am migrating from SQL 2008 on Win2003 to SQL 2014 on Win2012.

One of the jobs from the old system has this step:

```
if ('$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(INST))' -eq 'MSSQLSERVER') {$a = '\DEFAULT'} ELSE {$a = ''};
(Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR))$a).EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()
```

When I try to run this at a command line, on either server,it fails. It appears in the sql job some of the params are being set by sql agent.

What is this doing exasctly?  How to see it work?

Answer (score 1):

It's using SQL Agent Job step tokens ([explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575.aspx)) to set the path to one thing for default instances and another thing for named instances.  Then it's using the SQLSERVER provider to get a reference to a (policy?) object for the instance and call a method on it.

Comment: Since it only runs within SQL Agent, How can I validate that it is running without errors?

Comment: If it's a default instance, the INST will be MSSQLSERVER, if not, it will be the name of the instance.  SRVR will be the name of the machine that it's installed on.  Assuming you don't have any pathological naming for your servers or instances, you can ignore the ESCAPE_SQUOTE function completely.  With that in mind, you should be able to import the SQLPS module and run something pretty close.  I did in order to see what was going on.